# loading icon image in wordpress header

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to load a logo on my WP portfolio. This is the code that I am using in the functions:

```
$args = array(      
'width'   => 187,       
'height'  => 40,
'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri(). '/mauricio_bootstrap/img/portfolio.png',

);

add_theme_support( 'custom_header', $args );
```

And this is what I have in the header:

```
<a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"> <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" /> </a>
```

I'm aware this function is to load an image in the header. I am using Twitter bootstrap and I just want to load a logo in the header. If anyone has a better suggestion I'm open.

Comment: One option is to upload the logo to my gallery and include the link in the image without using the functions. but I was wondering if there is a neater way such as using the WordPress functions.

Comment: A second option that I am thinking is load a background image in the container that I want my logo to be from the WordPress css